# Disable right click on specific <div> or class=""

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my sample code:

**html**

```
<div>
    This is the Phone and NO ONE SHOULD RIGHT CLICK THIS! >:) </br>
        <img class="tlClogo" src="http://i.imgur.com/0atiS5C.jpg" style="height: 120px; width:120px;">
    </div></br></br></br></br>
    And this is the Keyboard, ofcourse yo can right click this :)</br>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/xkrKz1X.jpg" style="height: 120px; width:120px;">
```

**js**

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
    alert("This Logo is protected");return false;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79k52rvu/)

I want no one to be able to right click the 1st picture (cellphone) but other than that(keyboard) should be able to right click.

PS: I know this can be overriden by browsers but its okay :)

Comment: Some browsers? It can be overridden by all browsers.

Comment: your code works fine. You just forget to import jquery library in fiddle (under "Framework and Extensions" menu). see my update http://jsfiddle.net/79k52rvu/5/

Comment: i know but it doesn't do the function I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Came up with a solution.

```
$('.tlClogo').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79k52rvu/4/

EDIT 1: Only the first one is now NOT right-clickable!

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
        This is the Phone and NO ONE SHOULD RIGHT CLICK THIS! >:) </br>
        <img class="tlClogo" src="http://i.imgur.com/0atiS5C.jpg" style="height: 120px; width:120px;">
        </div>
        </br></br></br></br>
        And this is the Keyboard, ofcourse yo can right click this :)</br>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xkrKz1X.jpg" style="height: 120px; width:120px;">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('.tlClogo').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
                return false;
            }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2: Provided an HTML-doc